# Best way to replicate db into other systems

Tags: database, oracle, replication, enterprise

What is the best way to replicate the update stream to a large (6TB) oracle db into another non-DBMS system?  I don't need to "bulk load" the oracle db, but merely want to flow all updates into another home-grown system in near realtime (10s latency or less).  Updates happen at the rate of 150 rows/second representing 10s of megabytes per second.

For clarity, let me emphasize that I am not replicating from one db to another.  This is an application integration problem: I need to replicate from a db into an in-house, non-db application.  I've thought of using an enterprise service bus, but that seems inappropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'non-DBMS system'?

Answer (score 2):

So you're wanting to implement a log based replication scheme that just pumps the transaction log off to a different file system? There are a number of commercial products that will let you do this, the better known ones being [SharePlex](http://www.quest.com/shareplex-for-oracle/) and [GoldenGate](http://www.goldengate.com/technology/tdm.html), plus there's even an open source one called [Zizzy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zizzy), but I can't say that I've tried it.

***edit 1:*** if you're not wanting to feed the updates into another database, [GoldenGate's Event-Driven Architecture](http://www.goldengate.com/solutions/eda.html) provides a means to hook up the replication to a JMS message bus. For application integration, this is the option that I'd go for.

***edit 2:*** if using a message bus isn't the way you want to go, the only other sensible alternative that I can see is to get your hands dirty and use Oracle's [LogMiner](http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/availability/htdocs/LogMinerOverview.htm) API. IIRC, this is what Oracle uses for features like Streams and DataGuard and it's likely what most Change Data Capture solutions are based on, under the hood.

Comment: I will take a look at these products.  However, they don't quite seem like the right thing because the system receiving the updates is not a db and needs to read the replicated data; receiving the transaction logs would require that the logs be parsed in order to retrieve the data wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you just wanted to back up the logs on a different file system. What do you want to do with them once they're on this 'other system'??

Comment: The original database contains a hierarchy of information (a links to b, b links to c and d, etc.).   The secondary system wants to represent the data in a large matrix in order to perform linear algebra.   The feed is for moving the data (in near reatime) from the db into the linear algebra system.

Comment: and this needs to be realtime? You can't just create a view that represents your matrix and query that?

Comment: also, you have to consider the "cost" of replication, unless you've got some nice hardware replicating over the network is going to throttle your write times